# Store user input in an array database

Tags: javascript, html, database, vue.js

I'm trying to create an advertisement website where users create a profile with all their details and pictures in their individual profiles but to do this I need to store it in an array in a backend database so that I can retrieve them later.
This is how the backend javascript looks.

```
export const useProfileStore = defineStore('profile', {
  state: () => {
    return { 
      firstName: "Ellen",
      lastName: "Hopegar",
      email: "me@luddb.com"

    }
  },
})
```

This is sort of what I need the array to look like just with a lot more input being stored in them.

```
const users = [
  {
    firstname: "Fred",
    lastName: "Boy",
    email: "abc@t.com",
  },
  {
    firstname: "Tom",
    lastName: "Boy",
    email: "abc@t.com",
  },
  {
    firstname: "Jerry",
    lastName: "Boy",
    email: "abc@t.com",
  },
  {
    firstname: "Sam",
    lastName: "Boy",
    email: "abc@t.com",
  },
  {
    firstname: "Ben",
    lastName: "Boy",
    email: "abc@t.com",
  }]
```

I'm trying to make it so that i can use it in Vue.js like this for the icons

```
 <div v-for="user in users" :key="user.firstName" class="bg-slate-400 hover:bg-slate-800 w-64 p-4 rounded-xl shadow flex m-2 cursor-pointer">
    <div class="w-10">
      <img alt="Vue logo" src="../assets/logo.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="ml-4">
      <p class="font-bold">{{ user.firstname }} {{ user.lastName }}</p>
      <p class="-mt-1 text-xs">{{ user.email }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Heres where the input is coming from a in a different vue.js

```
<form class="review-form" @submit.prevent="onSubmit">
<div id= "app">
 <div>
 
             <input id="name" v-model="name" type="text" placeholder="Name">
            <input id="email" v-model="email" type="text" placeholder="Email">
           <input id="phone" v-model="phone" type="text" placeholder="Phone no.">
           <input id="age" v-model="age" type="text" placeholder="Age">
```

I also have file input i need to store in arrays as well, i hope this makes sense i just dont know how to store the input into an array like the one i showed so that im able to use it on multiple different pages and it needs to be put into an array when they create there profile once they hit the onsubmit button, sorry this is so long any help would really be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think your element data should be generated as an array, not an object, so you can facilitate this array on the html page, and when you click submit, you can insert the latest data into this array, shouldn't that be the case ?

Comment: No I need to store it in an array in a database so they I can retrieve the data for the profiles on other pages and I wont actually be able to save any data on the HTML page I don't think. Thanks though

Comment: The answer could be improved by providing an example.

Answer (score 0):

So if you want to reuse the values you need a store that can hold the array of objects

```
export const usersStore = defineStore('users', {
  state: () => {
    return { 
      users: []
    }
  },
})
```

and when the user clicks a submit button you push your formatted obj to the `users` array

```
const store = usersStore()

store.users.push(user)
```